# .htaccess RewriteRule help needed

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need a .htaccess RewriteRule to redirect

http://www.mydomain.comu/240/03/Test2/Test2.html

to

http://www.mydomain.comu/index.php?page_id=240&sub_page_link=03

I previously had below which worked ok, but does not work for a sub page link?

RewriteRule ([0-9]+)(.*).html$ index.php?page_id=$1

Your comments or feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Give us an example of a link that doesn't work, and what you want it to do.

Comment: the link http://www.mydomain.comu/240/03/Test2/Test2.html does not work, how do I get the 240 and 03 and then send to /index.php?page_id=240&sub_page_link=03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\d+)/\w+/\w+\.html index.php?page_id=$1&sub_page_link=$2 [L,R=301]
```

- `^` asserts that we are at the beginning of the path
- `(\d+)/(\d+)/` captures the digits to Group1 1 and 2
- `\w+/\w+\.html` matches the tail end of the url
- `$1` and `$2` are back-references to Groups 1 and 2.

Let me know if this works! :)

Comment: would it be easier to create a rule if I had  a hyphen between the numbers?www.mydomain.comu/240-03/Test2/Test2.html

Comment: For some reason I introduced a small typo when I pasted the rule. It's not `R-301` but `R=301`. Give that a try.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that and corrected it but still would not work, I just can't work it out, I also tried adding to the link as below but still no luck.http://www.mywebsite.com/subpage/240/10/Test2/Test2.html

http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?page_id=240&sub_page_link=10


RewriteRule    ^subpage/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/\.html$   /index.php?page_id=$1&sub_page_link=$2    [NC,L]    # Process subpages

Comment: Before the rule, do you have `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: #This will match any URL that starts with /Web/##/##/ 
RewriteRule ^We/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)*$ /index.php?page_id=$1&sub_page_link=$2    [NC,L]